# Is a Kummer surface unirational over a sufficiently large finite field of characteristic 2?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, algebraic-surfaces

Let $A$ be a supersingular abelian surface over a sufficiently large finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ of characteristic $2$ and let $K_A = A/(-1)$ be the Kummer surface. Shioda ("Kummer surfaces in characteristic 2") and Katsura ("On Kummer surfaces in characteristic 2") proved that $K_A$ is rational.

There is the open conjecture about $\mathbb{F}_q$-unirationality of a rational surface with a smooth $\mathbb{F}_q$-point. See, for example, "Rational varieties: algebra, geometry and arithmetic" by Manin and Tsfasman.

Let $A$ be $\mathbb{F}_q$-simple, it est, $A$ isn't isogenous a direct product of 2 elliptic curves over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Is $K_A$ unirational over $\mathbb{F}_q$ in this case? In particular, what is $\mathbb{F}_q$-minimal smooth model for $K_A$?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Is the following interpretation correct: You have a simple abelian variety $A$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. You are assuming that $A$ is isogenous to a product of supersingular elliptic curves after some finite extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then your question is whether $K_A$ is unirational over $\mathbb{F}_q$?

Comment: Yes, all right.

Comment: This question looks difficult. For example, in the easier case of del Pezzo surfaces, this is currently unknown: Every del Pezzo surface $S$ of degree $1$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ has a rational point, yet it is unknown whether every $S$ is actually unirational over $\mathbb{F}_q$. Such a surface $S$ even has an elliptic fibration, so it is quite similar to your case.

Comment: Is $K_A$ birationally isomorphic over $\mathbb{F}_q$ to an elliptic surface?

Comment: It certainly obtains an elliptic fibration after a finite field extension, given by projecting onto one of the elliptic curves. I'm not sure about over the ground field.